# 取得したデータの10進数数値文字参照を元のテキストに変換したい。

Tags: swift, html

以下のコードで取得したHTMLソースの、2バイト文字が&#xxxxxとなってしまう。
10進数数値文字参照をテキスト文字列に変換したい。
変換のヒントでも大歓迎です。

```
// 通信先のURLを生成
let myUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://k2k.sagawa-exp.co.jp/p/sagawa/web/okurijosearch.do?okurijoNo=123456789012")!

// リクエストを生成
print(myUrl)
let myRequest:NSURLRequest  = NSURLRequest(URL: myUrl)

// 送信処理を始める.
let res:NSData? = try! NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(myRequest, returningResponse: nil) as? NSData

// 帰ってきたデータを文字列に変換.
if let myData:String = NSString(data:res!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
    // 文字コード指定で正しくStringへ変換できた時の処理
    print(myData)
}
```

以下、帰ってくるデータの一部です。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<title>&#20304;&#24029;&#24613;&#20415; - &#12304;&#12362;&#33655;&#29289;&#21839;&#12356;&#21512;&#12431;&#12379;&#12469;&#12540;&#12499;&#12473;&#12305;</title>
    <meta charset="Windows-31J">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NONE">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="copyright" content="&#20304;&#24029;&#24613;&#20415;&#26666;&#24335;&#20250;&#31038;(c)">
```

以下略

下記のリンク先で、している変換をSwiftで実現したいのです。
[2] 10進数数値文字参照を文字列に変換　の部分です。
http://www.benricho.org/moji_conv/15.html

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 最終的に、プログラマがなにを得たいかによって、回答が変わってきます。UIWebView、WKWebViewに渡して表示するなら、文字列をそのまま渡せばいいし、UILabelなどで表示するなら、NSAttributedStringでどうにかなりそうです。utf-8や、Shift-JISにエンコードするのが目的というのが、おそらくいちばんやっかいです。

Comment: 少し質問を変えてみました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CFStringTransform(_: CFMutableString!, _: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFRange>, _: CFString!, _: Bool) -> Bool`を使って変換するのが簡単です。

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableStringRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringTransform

数値文字参照から変換するにはtransform IDに`Any-Hex/XML10`を指定して、`reverse`パラメータは`true`とします。

```
CFStringTransform(str, nil, "Any-Hex/XML10", true)
```

例えば、下記のようにします。

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string:"http://k2k.sagawa-exp.co.jp/p/sagawa/web/okurijosearch.do?okurijoNo=123456789012")!
let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: myUrl)

let res = try! NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(myRequest, returningResponse: nil)

if let myData = NSString(data:res, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    let str = NSMutableString(string: myData)
    CFStringTransform(str, nil, "Any-Hex/XML10", true)
    print(str)
}
```

Comment: すっきり解決です。ありがとうございます。